# QML Camera focus doesn't work

Tags: android, qt, qml, android-camera, qtquick2

How to focus with QML `Camera` on Android? I've tried all `focusMode` but nothing works. Camera apps correctly focus on my device.

Here my QML file:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtMultimedia 5.2

Item {
    property int scanerButtonWidth: 80
    property int scanerButtonHeight: 60

    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: scanerButtonHeight + 10
        color: Qt.rgba(0,0,0,1)
    }

    VideoOutput {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        source: camera
        anchors.fill: parent
        autoOrientation: true
    }

    Camera {
        id: camera
        imageProcessing.whiteBalanceMode: CameraImageProcessing.WhiteBalanceFlash
        captureMode: Camera.CaptureStillImage
        exposure {
            exposureMode: Camera.ExposureAuto
        }

        focus {
            focusMode: Camera.FocusContinuous
            focusPointMode: Camera.FocusPointCenter
        }

        imageCapture {
            onImageCaptured: {
                otpGeneratorApp.scanedQR_Code( preview, false, type )
                qrCodeScanner.visible = false
            }
        }
    }


    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: scanerButtonHeight + 10
        y: parent.height - ( height )
        color: Qt.rgba(0,0,0,1)

        Button {
            id: captureButton;
            width: scanerButtonWidth;
            height: scanerButtonHeight;
            x: parent.width * 0.5 - ( width / 2);
            y: parent.height - ( height + 5);
            text: qsTr( "[O]" );
            onClicked: {
                 camera.imageCapture.capture();
            }
        }

        Button {
            id: focus
            width: scanerButtonWidth;
            height: scanerButtonHeight;
            text: qsTr("Focus");
            x: captureButton.x + ( captureButton.width + 10 );
            y: parent.height - ( height + 5);
            onClicked: {
                 camera.searchAndLock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Qt 5.4 or below, you **cannot**. There is a bug in `QCamera` that prevents the autofocus to be triggered. See the bug and a way to solve it [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42224#comment-268133).

A solution has been merged and the bug is solved since Qt 5.5.